# Promise .then() chains: second .then run before the first?? o.0

Tags: javascript, file, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm trying to create a new File object from blob data in a .then structure, and after in the second .then, read info of this file.

But the second then run before the first end, so the file object isn't filled yet.

Is that a normal behavior? Should I make an async function, called in the first then to ensure the second one is strictly called after?

```
      let output = {file: {}, file_infos: {}},
          image = FileAPI.Image(src_file);
      await Promise.all(Object.keys(parameters).map(async (parameter_name) => { // Pass file threw all modifiers (resizing, rotation, overlaying)
        try {
          image = await FileMethods[parameter_name](image, parameters[parameter_name]);
            return image;
        }
        catch(err) {
          console.log(err);
        };
      }))
      .then((output_image) => {
        output_image[0].toBlob((blob) => {
          output.file = new File([blob], src_file.name); // Need this to be fullfilled before step2
          console.log('step1');
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('step2');
        FileAPI.getInfo(output.file, (err/**String*/, infos/**Object*/) => {
          if( !err ){
            output.file_infos = infos;
          } else {
            console.log("this is triggered because output.file isn't filled yet");
          }
        })
      });
      // console.log(output);
      return output;
```

console shows me:

`step2
this is triggered because output.file isn't filled yet
step1`

Thanks for helps :)

Comment: there are already correct answers. just wanted to say it would be a good addition if you use async-await instead of promise then chains.

Comment: mixing await with `.then` is not the best practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two asynchronous functions in the two .then's do not return a Promise, so first they need to be "Promisified", also, since you're already using `async/await` don't use a promise `.then` chain

```
const image = FileAPI.Image(src_file);
const output_image = await Promise.all(Object.keys(parameters).map(async(parameter_name) => {
    try {
        image = await FileMethods[parameter_name](image, parameters[parameter_name]);
        return image;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    };
}));
const file = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => output_image[0].toBlob((blob) => 
    resolve(new File([blob], src_file.name))
));
const file_infos = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => FileAPI.getInfo(file, (err, file_infos) => {
    if (!err) {
        resolve(file_infos);
    } else {
        reject("this is triggered because output.file isn't filled yet");
    }
));
return {file, file_infos};
```

---

A note about

```
const output_image = await Promise.all(Object.keys(parameters).map(async(parameter_name) => {
    try {
        image = await FileMethods[parameter_name](image, parameters[parameter_name]);
        return image;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    };
}));
```

you're essentially doing `return await FileMethods[parameter_name](image, parameters[parameter_name])` - so, you really don't need in this case an async/await pattern, just return the Promise in the .map

```
const output_image = await Promise.all(Object.keys(parameters).map((parameter_name) => 
    FileMethods[parameter_name](image, parameters[parameter_name]);
));
```

Or, even nicer (in my opinion)

```
const output_image = await Promise.all(Object.entries(parameters).map((p_name, p_value) =>
    FileMethods[p_name](image, p_value)
));
```

---

> Alternatively, to use Promise .then chains and no async/await

```
const image = FileAPI.Image(src_file);
return Promise.all(Object.keys(parameters).map(parameter_name => FileMethods[parameter_name](image, parameters[parameter_name])))
.then(output_image => new Promise((resolve, reject) => output_image[0].toBlob((blob) => 
    resolve(new File([blob], src_file.name))
)))
.then(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => FileAPI.getInfo(file, (err, file_infos) => {
    if (!err) {
        resolve({file, file_infos});
    } else {
        reject("this is triggered because output.file isn't filled yet");
    }
)));
```

Comment: Thanks!I knew I could resolved the problem with a new promise in then but I'm not pretty comfortable yet with multiple level promises. I agree with you for your "imo" message, it's nicer! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Searching about Object.entries. Which is not the efficient way (in my case) because it do not guaranteed order, and for some optimizing reasons I need to. For example, the first parameter in the list is always "resize", so it's more efficient to rotate, transform, overlay or whatever a smaller image. I'm working with clothes's web-merchants and they photos can be really big XD

Comment: yet, you use Object.keys @Romain'Maz'BILLOIR - and object.keys/values/entries all return in the same order as `for...in`

Answer (score 1):

`toBlob` is probably asynchronous. Change the first `.then` to this:

```
.then((output_image) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => output_image[0].toBlob((blob) => {
    output.file = new File([blob], src_file.name); // Need this to be fullfilled before step2
    console.log('step1');
    resolve();
  }));
})
```

Comment: @Bergi normally i would agree. But in OP:s code `output` is a global variable and the following `.then` doesn't expect an argument. So in this case, no, it should not be `resolve(output)`.

Comment: probably need to do the same for `FileAPI.getInfo` - if you want the return output to return everything

Answer (score 1):

`.toBlob()` returns instantly because it uses the asynchronous callback pattern.

What you want is to return a promise that resolves when the work is done. So you could do something like this:

```
.then((output_image) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      output_image[0].toBlob((blob) => {
        output.file = new File([blob], src_file.name); // Need this to be fullfilled before step2
        console.log('step1');
        res();
      });
    });
  })
```

Comment: probably need to do the same for `FileAPI.getInfo` - if you want the return output to return everything